# Есть ли библиотеки облегчающие построение графиков на SVG?

Tags: svg

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли библиотеки упрощающие и облегчающие построение графиков (по осям X и Y) используя SVG?

Comment: [Автор любит задавать один и тот же вопрос на всех сервисах мира][1]


  [1]: https://toster.ru/q/85006#answer_273756

Comment: @papagaj и что в этом криминального?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По части всевозможной визуализации данных [d3.js](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery) вне конкуренции.